# c# How to get index of panel control placed in tabcontrol's current tabpage

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using this code to get the panel control index placed in the current tabpage controls list of tabcontrol1 , but I am not able to do it . How to get the index of this panel ? The name of the panel is same as label1.Text

```
int count = 0;int index=0;
          foreach (var item in tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls)
          {
              if (item.Name == label1.Text)
              {
                  index = count;
                  break;
              }
              else
              {
                  count++;
              }
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls)
{
     if (item is Panel)
     {
          Panel panel = (Panel)item;
          if (panel.Name == label1.Text)
          {
               index = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.IndexOf(panel);
               break;
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `index = count;` with the fllowing:

```
index = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.IndexOf(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your checking control names, you don't need to iterate over them since controls can't have the same name in a form. Try to find it from tab control's controls collection:

```
int index = tabControl1.Controls.IndexOfKey(label1.Text);
```

Or

```
int index = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.SelectedIndex].Controls.IndexOfKey(label1.Text);
```